# Extjs: override specific listeners

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have a window component which I'm extending to create different windows. Now, the `close()` and `hide()` listener functions are the same across board, but the `afterrender()` changes with each instance.

So I have something like:

```
Ext.define('abc.xyz.BaseWindow', {
    extend : "Ext.Window",
    listeners: {
        hide: function(el, eOpts){
            console.log('hide');
        },
        close: function(el, eOpts){
            console.log('close');
        }   
    }
});
```

And:

```
Ext.define('abc.xyz.MyWindow', {
        extend : "abc.xyz.BaseWindow",
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function(el, eOpts){
                console.log('afterrender');
            }
        }
    });
```

However, the whole `listeners` object is overridden and `hide()` and `close()` are never called. Is there any way around this, except to specify `hide()` and `close()` in every extended window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your functions in the window, call them and override them in the window like this:

```
Ext.define('abc.xyz.BaseWindow', {
    extend : "Ext.Window",
    onHide: function(){
        console.log('hide');
    },
    onShow: function(el, eOpts){
        console.log('close');
    },
    onAfterRender: function(el, eOpts){
        console.log('first after render');
    },

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            listeners: {
                hide: me.onHide,
                show: me.onShow
                afterrender: me.onAfterRender
            }
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

And:

```
Ext.define('abc.xyz.MyWindow', {
    extend : "abc.xyz.BaseWindow",
    onAfterRender: function(el, eOpts){
        console.log('second after render');
    }
});
```

Or if you don't have an afterrender in the base class you just add a listener with (on) like  Evan Trimboli sais

```
Ext.define('abc.xyz.MyWindow', {
    extend : "abc.xyz.BaseWindow",
    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);

        me.on('afterrender', function(el, eOpts){
            console.log('second after render');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: In this case yes. But if you have one in the base class both handlers will be called.. Depends on what you want: override or add extra listener :)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I ended up calling `onAfterRender()` from the listeners config in base and specifying the function in extended windows. It works. No need for initComponent or applyIf

Answer (score 0):

Use constructor and merge listeners:

```
Ext.define('abc.xyz.BaseWindow', {
    extend : "Ext.Window",
    
    listeners: {
        hide: function(el, eOpts) {
            console.log('hide');
        },
        close: function(el, eOpts) {
            console.log('close');
        },
    },
    
    constructor: function (config) {
        const { listeners } = config || {};

        if (listeners) {
            config.listeners = { ...this.listeners, ...listeners };
        }

        this.callParent([config]);
    },
});
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**